# Need to find the id of Sites.FullControl.All in the SharePoint Api group

Tags: azure, powershell, api, sharepoint, azure-active-directory

I need to add the Sites.FullControl.All api permission in an app registration via powershell, but i can't find the id . already have find the id of various api like AllSites.FullControl with the command

`$svcSharePoint = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Office 365 SharePoint Online" }

$svcSharePoint.Oauth2Permissions | FT ID, Value
`

Any Ideas?

This is what I'm expecting.

[image: Result Description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tested in my environment. I'm able to retrieve the IDs of Application permissions successfully like below:***

[image]

Please note that **`Sites.FullControl.All`** is an **Application Permission** not **Delegated Permission.**

Using below cmdlet, you will only get a list of ***delegated*** permissions IDs.

```
$svcSharePoint.Oauth2Permissions | FT ID, Value
```

To get a list of ***application*** permissions IDs, you have to make use of below cmdlet:

```
$svcSharePoint.AppRoles | FT ID, Value
```

The ID of **`Sites.FullControl.All`** permission is ***678536fe-1083-478a-9c59-b99265e6b0d3***