# Unable to fetch ID of SharePoint API permissions

Tags: azure-ad-b2b, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I am trying to fetch GUID of ProjectWebApp.FullControl and
ProjectWebAppReporting.Read and add them to Sharepoint Api group.

I tried using below command to find IDs:

```
$result = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Office 365 SharePoint Online" }

$result.AppRoles | FT ID, Value
```

I can see Ids of permissions, like User.ReadAll, Sites.FullControl.All etc., but I cant find Ids of ProjectWebApp.FullControl and
ProjectWebAppReporting.Read permissions.

Can anyone help me to get GUIDs? or where Am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried in my environment and got the IDs successfully:***

The command you are using will fetch the IDs of Application permissions.

Please note that, **`ProjectWebApp.FullControl`** and **`ProjectWebAppReporting.Read`**  are Delegated permissions.

To fetch the IDs of Delegated permissions, modify the command like below:

```
$result = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Office 365 SharePoint Online" }

$result.Oauth2Permissions | FT ID, Value
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[azure - Need to find the id of Sites.FullControl.All in the SharePoint Api group - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71739038/need-to-find-the-id-of-sites-fullcontrol-all-in-the-sharepoint-api-group/71749550#71749550)